# Asp.net Event code 3003

Tags: asp.net

My event log has thousands of entries for code 3003 which says "A validation error has occurred.". I am properly handling the validation on server side and error is caught in global.asax and proper message is shown to the user. I don't want to add code to handle the characters on client side by javascript or turning on ValidateRequest=false
My concern is only the event log entries and is there any way I can stop asp.net not to log event 3003 in event log?

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false"/>
```

To your web.config to apply it to the whole site.

**Edit:**

Goes in the System.web section.

Comment: I already know that but I cannot add that to whole site. I have mix of pages. Some need html input and some not. Rather than validating all pages which don't need html input, I handle the error at one place(global.asax). I even could not find how to clear programmetically the selected event ids from event log

Comment: Well then you are going to get these errors if you aren't validating input properly.

Comment: That means I have to validate on client or if to validate on server then I have to turn off validateRequest. Since this event is logged before running my page code, I have no control on it. So the only option is to turn of validateRequest. So the question is whether I validate properly or not, event will be logged as long as validateRequest=true